# Use of globals() for creating class instances

Tags: python, security, global-variables, instance

I am using [globals()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#globals) to create instances of classes on the fly.

For eg.

**animals.py**

```
class Cat():
    pass

class Dog():
    pass
```

**test.py**

```
#import animals

def create_animal():
    # Take 'which_animal' input from 
    # somewhere in form of string
    try:
    animal1 = globals()[which_animal]()
    catch:
    .
    .
```

I did this to avoid long if-else ladder.
What are pros and cons of this method ?
Is there any alternative method for the same ?
Is it creating security threat ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Any* name in your globals is accessible; this includes the `create_animal()` function, and anything you may have imported.

This does means that there *could* be a security risk, depending on what was imported. You should, at the very least, filter the objects found on the `__module__` attribute:

```
animal_cls = globals()[which_animal]
if animal_cls.__module__ != __name__:
    raise TypeError('Not a class defined in this module!')
animal1 = animal_cls()
```

The alternative is to put classes that you want accessible in some kind of data structure. You could use a new dictionary:

```
animals = {
    'Cat': Cat,
    'Dog': Dog,
}
```

You can have each class register itself (through a decorator) into such a mapping:

```
animals = {}

def registered(cls):
    animals[cls.__name__] = cls
    return cls

@registered
class Cat():
    pass

@registered
class Dog():
    pass
```

or you could use a base class; the `__subclasses__()` method then lets you list any and all derived classes:

```
class Animal(object):
    pass

class Cat(Animal):
    pass

class Dog(Animal):
    pass

animals = {cls.__name__: cls for cls in Animal.__subclasses__()}
```

Comment: Python3 exclusively now? or just decided to make an old style class for fun? :-)  (or following OP's code I suppose)

Comment: @mgilson: There, made the `object` base explicit. :-)